# Fibrosis vs stenosis vs sclerosis

Tags: muscles

I can't figure out the key distinguishing factors between these three and I keep seeing them being used almost interchangeably.

For example **aortic valve fibrosis** and **aortic valve stenosis**.

As much as I have understood:

- Fibrosis is related to muscle tissue and myofibrils
- Stenosis is the result of fibrosis, because muscle tissue loses the ability to expand
- Sclerosis is the thickening of the tissue

What are the distinguishing notes between them?

**update**

One example is [this](https://youtu.be/Xc1dHiFO25w) YouTube video from Ninja Nerds.

Comment: As you may know, on this site, prior research is required by the OP. It would be more helpful if you actually cited sources for the definitions of fibrosis, stenosis and sclerosis, e.g. ["this site defines fibrosis as..."](https://www.news-medical.net/health/What-is-Fibrosis.aspx), etc. By those means, you're much more likely to get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @anongoodnurse thank you so much. The question is updated.

Comment: To begin, look up the three terms in Wiktionary, which actually has a decent set of etymological connections for the words.  You'll see fibrosis is about [typically collagen] fibers, stenosis is about *narrowing*, and sclerosis is about *hardening*.  Of course, in any specific context these meanings don't get you that far by themselves - multiple sclerosis is about a lot more than hardening per se.

Answer (score 1):

You already answered yourself the question: these three words are here to designate different phases of a general process. This general process is triggered by the appearance of fibrosis, which is an alteration of a "normal" cicatrization process.

What happened -simplified way- is:

When a part of the body is attacked, a repair process is triggered. Stem cells activated and duplicate to replace the destroyed part of the body. But the process is not entirely "one for one":

- For genetic gene alteration reasons, some stem cells will not function
- Because the signal that triggers reparation could use various paths, some paths will push stem cells into differenciation, thus the end organ will have less stem cells that at the beginning
- For some reasons I don't understand to explain them, some tissues of the organ will expand faster than others. If parenchymal tissue is less expanded than connective tissue during the reparation phase, the overall new "material" (=a mix of the different types of tissues) in the destroyed part of the organ will be "dead tissue"

These three causes and their immediate consequence are called **fibrosis**.

Because of the third point, there is **stenosis** in the dead tissue: it cannot expand anymore.

Because the dead tissue is attacked again and again, it will be reduced and could not be replaced: this is **sclerosis**.